# Android Studio Emulator Shuts Down On Debug App

Tags: android, debugging, android-virtual-device

When I go to debug my app in Android Studio, I get the following:

```
03/11 16:52:58: Launching mobile
$ adb shell am start -n "com.gelakinetic.mtgfam.debug/com.gelakinetic.mtgfam.FamiliarActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.gelakinetic.mtgfam.debug.test | com.gelakinetic.mtgfam.debug
Waiting for application to come online: com.gelakinetic.mtgfam.debug.test | com.gelakinetic.mtgfam.debug
Waiting for application to come online: com.gelakinetic.mtgfam.debug.test | com.gelakinetic.mtgfam.debug
Connecting to com.gelakinetic.mtgfam.debug
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/ActivityThread: Application com.gelakinetic.mtgfam.debug is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/zygote: Debugger is active
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8834', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/chatty: uid=10079(com.gelakinetic.mtgfam.debug) identical 4 lines
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1498)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.gelakinetic.mtgfam.debug, PID: 9164
                  DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9164 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8834', transport: 'socket'
```

I'm sure it isn't the code, because it launches fine on my other computer and another person's.

I'm running the AVD in Software rendering mode because it crashes otherwise (I think it has to do with nouveau drivers?).

This DOES NOT happen when I launch normally (Green Arrow, Shift-F10).

This is a fresh installation of both Arch and Android Studio.